# Why my ubuntu 19.10 took too long to boot [more than 10 minutes]?

Tags: boot, 19.10

Yesterday, when I turned on my pc, my ubuntu was taking too long to start more than 10 minutes. Tired of this i held the power key to turn it off and again restarted it. Again the same thing happened. Then I decided to go to boot settings and did nothing, saved the changes and again started it. And it worked and started in less than a minute. But I really wanna know why this happened? So please someone tell me if you know the answer.
Today morning, again it was taking long time to start and I gathered all of my patience to see how much time does it take to boot up. After 40 minutes, I was tired of seeing the same screen. I lost my patience and hold the power key to close the computer and again pressed it to restart. Then it started in about some seconds. The same happened now- I had to turn it off once using power key and when i turned it on again it worked. But I don't wanna do this again and again.
Well! I have provided the screenshots that you may need to help me.

[It is the screenshot of my terminal for `free -h`, `grep -i swap /etc/fstab/` and `sudo blkid`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibf6r.png) [this is the first screenshot of smart data and smart test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZEcr.png)[this is the second screenshot of smart data and smart test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsXJW.png)

[this is the third screenshot of smart data and smart test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqGNV.png)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid`, and in the `Disks` app, show me screenshot(s) of the SMART Data (scrollable) window.

Comment: is this safe? I am asking because i am new to ubuntu [started just 1 week ago]. My habit is that I create a lot of mess even when i wanted to dualboot my pc[windows with ubuntu] i lost my windows 10.

Comment: Yes, these are safe. They give me information required to help solve your problem.

Comment: I want to upgrade my ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04. Do I upgrade before solving this problem or after solving this problem.

Comment: No, don't upgrade until you get this problem fixed. I reviewed your screenshots (thanks) and it looks like your HDD is failing. Give me a few minutes and I'll put together an answer for you. Your swap is also too small... but that's another problem.

Comment: Be sure to watch the boot sequence for things like networks and/or devices not being up. More than likely your drive is failing as noted in other answers. If you want to save some time (and avoid live disk troubleshooting), my advice to you is to just give up on this boot/root drive and install 20.xx to a 'new' SSD or spindle drive. After new system is up, add (meaning `mount`) the *old* HDD to the system again and gather/move any files you want saved to *new* system drive(s). Then format the *old* drive and test it for errors per other answers. You can then diagnose drive at your leisure.

Comment: ok heynnema i will tell you. Right now, I am backing up my files to avoid any kind of data loss. By the way, thanks for giving your precious time.

Comment: @heynnema- Approximately how many hours will it take to finish? When it will finish and i will reboot, will my problem be solved?

Comment: It may or may not be solved. You'll have to wait and see. Time? It depends on how large your disk is, and how big the Linux partition is. It could take a couple of hours, or longer, depending on how many bad blocks it finds. Just be very patient.

Comment: I wanted to inform you that it has completed and found 47 errors. Then I powered it off and removed the usb. Then I again pressed the power button to turn it on to see if it worked or not but again I saw the same screen with ubuntu written on it and five dots changing their colors continously for hours and still did not start.

Comment: You have to start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them, like your most recent comment... I almost missed it. The symptom of Ubuntu with 5 rotating dots was not mentioned in your original question. Do you know how to boot with nomodeset? There may be an easy fix. How old is your computer? Do you know what video card you have?

Comment: @hynnema I tried nomodeset yesterday and my ubuntu started. But it changed the resolution and it looked weird. So I decided to change it to the previous one and I removed nomodeset by using terminal. After that, I restarted it started working properly. I don't know how this has happened but it worked and now it does not take hours to boot. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @hynnema Since I don't need ubuntu anymore, I am going to install kali linux as my primary os because now I am comfortable with linux and ready to use it for everyday use and for learning ethical hacking.

Comment: nomodeset was just for testing, and yes, resolution would have probably changed. Because it booted, it gave more clues as to the fix. But of course, if you're going with kali, it's moot. If my answer was helpful in clearing your HDD of bad blocks (it found 47 errors), and it boots now, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HDD is failing, or your SATA cable is defective, and your swap is too small (we'll deal with this later).

**fsck**

Let's check your file system.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors

**bad block**

Let's see if we can work around the bad blocks on your HDD.

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `systemd-analyze` to get an overview of your boot times.

Example: `Startup finished in 12.749s (firmware) + 6.025s (loader) + 4.668s (kernel) + 9.488s (userspace) = 32.932s  graphical.target reached after 9.474s in userspace`

With `systemd-analyze blame`, you can see what the main offenders are in terms of boot time.

For me, these are the ones that take longer than one second:

```
6.535s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
1.094s dev-sda5.device
1.067s udisks2.service
1.029s smartmontools.service
...
```

Comment: And `systemd-analyze critical-chain` will show you what targets or services that everything else is waiting for.